# Assistance in deriving the trigonometric expression:

Tags: analysis, mathematical-physics, fluid-dynamics

The equation
$$\DeclareMathOperator{\Dd}{d\!}
\frac{\Dd y}{\Dd x} = \tan (\theta \pm \mu)\label{1}\tag{1}
$$ is not derived explicitly in the book "**Introduction to Numerical Techniques for Nonlinear Supersonic Flow**" by C. K. Chu. The book focuses on numerical techniques for solving nonlinear supersonic flow equations rather than providing a derivation for the equation.

As a result, I would like to derive the trigonometric equation \eqref{1}, as prescribed in the book.

- I attached an image here from the textbook for your reference. [Eq. 13.10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlSh7.png) is the equation, which I would like to derive from Eq. 13.9.
- I'm hereby attaching [what I have done](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72IbQ.jpg). I wasn't able to make it to the final possible result.

Can someone guide/correct me? Thank you

Comment: Hello Gonçalo, Thanks for your response. I attached the textbook reference for your understanding. Kindly check it

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is writing that
$$\sin 2\theta + \sin 2 \mu \ne \sin 2(\theta + \mu).$$
For example, with $\theta = \mu = \frac \pi 4$, \begin{align*}
\sin 2 \theta + \sin 2 \mu &= \sin \frac \pi 2 + \sin \frac \pi 2 = 2, \text{ but}\\ 
\sin2(\theta + \mu) &= \sin \pi = 0.
\end{align*}
You got as far as $$\frac{- \sin 2 \theta \pm \sin 2 \mu}{\cos 2 \theta + \cos 2 \mu},$$
which is correct.

Comment: Thank you kipf. Got my solution when you pointed out my mistake. Attaching the solution in the form of image here.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this query. Thank you
[Soution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvYhD.png)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Thank you. I'll do that from my next post. :-)